# Create Json String manually

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm trying to create a Json structure manually in Java. In the end, I need the a string representation of my Json object. Since my project already has a dependency to GSON, I wanted to use this. But after several hours of trying and googling, I think, I completely misunderstand something.

At the moment, I have the following (non-working) code:

```
JsonObject user_auth = new JsonObject();
user_auth.addProperty("user_name", username);
user_auth.addProperty("password", password);
JsonObject rest_data = new JsonObject();
Gson gson = new Gson();
rest_data.addProperty("user_auth", gson.toJson(user_auth));
rest_data.addProperty("application", APPLICATION_NAME);
String payload = gson.toJson(rest_data);
```

The problem I'm facing is that the "user_auth" element gets escaped quotes (\" instead of " when it is added to the outer element. How can I prevent this?
I also tried to use

```
rest_data.addProperty("user_auth", user_auth.toString());
```

but this did exactely the same.

Regards,

Comment: You're doubly-encoding your JSON.  Just add user_auth directly to the enclosing JsonObject, don't JSONify it.

Comment: (Before you do the toJson call your entire object structure should `toString` to look almost exactly like the intended JSON result.)

Comment: (Converting JSON to and from Maps/Lists is perfectly natural and uncomplicated.  Stuff like Jackson makes it more complicated, not less.)

Comment: Hot Licks' comment should be an answer, and accepted, as it solves OP's question concisely and completely without editorial comment. (Just remove the "toJson" from user_auth, win!)

Answer (score 13):

Writing the JSON manually is not a good solution.

It seems that you encode user_auth twice.

Try this instead:

```
JsonObject user_auth = new JsonObject();
user_auth.addProperty("user_name", username);
user_auth.addProperty("password", password);

JsonObject rest_data = new JsonObject();
rest_data.addProperty("user_auth", user_auth);
rest_data.addProperty("application", APPLICATION_NAME);

Gson gson = new Gson();
String payload = gson.toJson(rest_data);
```

Comment: Strong disagree. Writing JSON manually is frequently a good solution. Asserted without evidence, dismissed without evidence.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is directly convert POJO into JSON.

**1. Create POJO object**

i.e. user class:

```
class User {

    @JsonProperty("user_name") // this annotation helps you to specify
                               // property name in result json
    private String userName;

    @JsonProperty("first_name")
    private String firstName;

    // ...

    // getters and setters here, hashcode, equals, etc.

}
```

**2. Convert POJO to JSON string**

for example:

```
User user = new User("superlogin", "superpass", ...);

String jsonString = new Gson().toJson(user);
```

Thats all :)

I think it's more convenient way than build json structure manually.

Answer (score 0):

Use the addProperty() for the user_auth and then for the rest_data you need the payload.

```
String payloadJSON = gson.toJson(rest_data);
```

Answer (score -2):

If you dont wont to add external jar then, try this

return "{UPLOAD:"+upload+",UPLOADSTATUS:"+perUpload+",TRANSCODE:"+transcode+",TRANSCODESTATUS:"+transcodestatus+"}";

Comment: bad advice in long term, imagine if you have 20 properties and 10 entities with manual to-json method (as you suggest). one day you need to add new 5 properties for each object. it's kinda little hell